# Use select() with mbedtls library

Tags: mbedtls

I am creating a proxy using the mbedtls library.

In the library itself, there are example how to read and write in the ssl socket, using for example `mbedtls_ssl_read` function. There is also a minimalistic client example, in the file `ssl_client1.c`.

But I am stuck when I want to "wait for data", for example using a `select` function.

I tried (but it is wrong), to take the underlying file descriptor inside the `mbedtls_net_context` and do a `select()` on it.

The problem now is that if I don't read everything the first time I call `mbedtls_ssl_read` (that is, I am reading less data than what the ssl socket has received), anyway all the data is read from the underlying socket (so, the `select()` does not trigger anything because there is no data in the underlying socket anymore), but the data I have not read is somehow "stuck" in the ssl context of mbedtls library. If I force the `mbedtls_ssl_read` function, I can read the remaining data, so it is not lost. But I don't know that there is more data, because the `select()` function has not triggered anything.

Well, in conclusion, I would like to have a `select` function in the mbedtls library, that could check not only the underlying socket, but also the ssl context, and can tell me that I need to call `mbedtls_ssl_read` again.

I could not find any. Someone could point me to the right function, or give me an example?

Comment: "but the data I have not read is somehow "stuck" in the ssl context of mbedtls library" - what do you mean by that? When you call `mbedtls_ssl_read` and don't read all the available data from the socket, the socket is still ready for reading

Comment: Thats what I would expect, but it seems not the case. Indeed the next call to "select()" would just wait undefinitely